# direct_mail uses wrong templavoila template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

**No matter what I do doesntwork.com uses the templavoila template of work.com.
I want doesntwork.com to use its own templavoila template, but dunno how.**

---

I use directmail with multiple domains in one typo3 tree. E.g. the domains: works.com and doesntwork.com. Directmail works with the first domain (works.com), but not with the second domain (doesntwork.com).

---

- works.com has its own sysfolder for directmail (named WorkNewsletters)
- doesntwork.com has its own sysfolder for directmail (named DoesntWorkNewsletters)

---

- works.com has its own sysfolder for templavoila (named WorkStorage)
- doesntwork.com has its own sysfolder for templavoila (named DoesntWorkStorage)

---

- The WorkNewsletters folder uses a green templavoila template for all it's subpages. This template is located in the WorkStorage folder.
- The DoesntWorkNewsletters folder uses a red templavoila template for all it's subpages. This template is located in the DoesntWorkStorage folder.

---

I create a new directmail with the wizard, by

- choosing the directmail sysfolder for doesntwork.com
- selecting Internal Pages
- selecting Click here to create a new page that you can later send as a direct mail.
- typing in some dummy text and create the page
- still via the wizard, select the page created in the previous step
- I send it as a test email to to my own mailadress

---

Details about the installation:

- typo3 version 4.4.6
- direct_mail version 2.6.9
- Realurl is not used.
- Cronjob runs every 2 minute.

---

In the root template of DoesntWork I have added this to the setup

```
config.baseURL = http://doesntwork.com/
```

In the root template of Work I have added this to the setup

```
config.baseURL = http://work.com/
```

---

On the WorkNewsletter folder I have added a template with this is the setup field

```
plugin.tx_directmail_pi1.siteUrl = http://work.com/
```

On the DoesntWorkNewsletter folder I have added a template with this is the setup field

```
plugin.tx_directmail_pi1.siteUrl = http://doesntwork.com/
```

---

I have tried to send mails by using the backend when logged in at `http://doesntwork.com/typo3/` but it didn't make any difference.

---

**Anything obvious I have done wrong? What can I do to debug it?**

Comment: if you look a the page used to make the mail in front end is it the good template? And if you look at the object browser have you got any wrong configuration in directmail that are comming from work.com?

Comment: I see the right templavoila template when looking at the page in the frontend. I cannot see the work.com domain mentioned in the object browser. Somehow the content fetching happens from the wrong domain.

Comment: No solution yet. I have just configured realurl for the two domains and added "config.typolinkCheckRootline = 1", but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i configured realurl for both domains, I started getting this error message

> The HTML content could not be fetched.

Previously could not see any error message.

It helped me realize that I had to specify a domain here

```
Direct Mail
Configuration
SET DEFAULT VALUES FOR MAIL CONTENT FETCHING OPTIONS:
Domain of internal links:
```

Now newsletters works for both domains with the right templavoila template.